# Как получить текущего пользователя сайта?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Не удаётся неявно преобразовать тип "string" в тип "Author"

Скриншот ошибки:

[image: Скрин ошибки]

Класс Thread:

```
public class Thread
{
    public Thread() => Posts = new List<Post>();

    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public  User Author { get; set; }       
    //public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Content { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ForumId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Forum Forum { get; set; }
}
```

Класс User:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Класс ApplicationUser (не активен)*

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public String AvatarPath { get; set; }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я ещё могу получить аутентифицированного пользователя?

Comment: Вдумчиво прочтите эту статью https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions
Суть в том, что таким образом вы не можете преобразовать тип string в тип Author

Answer (score 0):

Вам не надо получать полностью аутентифицированного пользователя для того, чтобы подставить его параметры в вашу сущность Thread.

Вполне достаточно указать Id аутентифицированного пользователя.

Посмотрите на то, как у вас в модели объявлена ссылка на сущность Forum:

```
public class Thread
{
    ...
    [Required]
    public int ForumId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Forum Forum { get; set; }
}
```

Сделайте по аналогии:

```
public class Thread
{
    ...
    [Required]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
}
```

А устанавливать Author не нужно: когда дело дойдёт до сохранения - всё сохранится правильным образом.

Ну а id пользователя можно получить например так:

```
int currentUserId = int.Parse(this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
```

(у меня переделанные на int, если у вас строковые - можете убрать int.Parse)

Comment: Подробнее тут: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38751616/5752652

Comment: A K, Спасибо большое за наводку. Да, у меня Id именно числовые. У меня свои таблицы и Аутентификация на основе куки. Поэтому я и думал как-то получить пользователя а потом взять у него Id. Ведь сохранить нужно именно его Id.

Comment: @Новичок При помощи _userManager вы можете вытащить любые параметры любого пользователя, но ведь вам только текущий нужен - а потому вполне достаточно данных в this.User

Comment: @A K Я не использовал _userManager, потому как у меня простая Аутентификация на основе куки https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/15.2.php Поэтому и возникла необходимость в Author добавить Id текущего пользователя из своей таблицы, а не из дефолтной AspNetUsers.

Comment: @Новичок В - вовремя )) Уже написан ответ, а вы только спохватились указать существенные части вопроса.

Comment: @A K Простите пожалуйста, ник говорит сам за себя...

Comment: в asp.net-mvc & web-api2 Id пользователя можно получить так: `User.Identity.GetUserId<int>()`, где метод `GetUserId` является *обобщенным*, может в `core` тоже так можно