# Как получить текущего пользователя темы?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Повторный вопрос, ввиду собственной глупости в формулировке...

У меня простая Аутентификация на основе куки metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/15.2.php

Не удаётся неявно преобразовать тип "string" в тип "Author"

Скриншот ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс Thread:

```
public class Thread
{
    public Thread() => Posts = new List<Post>();

    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public  User Author { get; set; }       
    //public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Content { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ForumId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Forum Forum { get; set; }
}
```

Класс User:

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public int? RoleId { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

Класс ApplicationUser (не активен)*

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public String AvatarPath { get; set; }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я ещё могу получить Id аутентифицированного пользователя?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить текущего пользователя сайта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899562/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: Не стоит многократно задавать однотипные вопросы. Вы вполне можете восстановить и отредактировать старый вопрос - в нём гораздо больше и правильнее информации для ответа на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @A K Восстановил. Там меня уже в чат отпинывают(

Answer (score 0):

А с чего вы взяли, что оно должно преобразовываться? `Name` у вас строка, т.е базовый тип и вы его хотите неявно преобразовать в объект.

Если вы сами не определили операции неявного преобразования, то оно само никак не преобразуются.

Очевидно, что вам нужно воспользоваться оператором `new` и передать в конструктор стринговый параметр, если таковой конструктор имеет.